# Have sibling views re-render from a Marionette childview

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a pretty standard Marionette Itemview and CompositeView that looks like this:

```
  List.LessonType = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "lesson_types/list/lesson_type",
    tagName: "tr",

    triggers: {
      "click #edit-lesson-type" : "edit:lesson:type:clicked"
    }
  });

  List.LessonTypes = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "lesson_types/list/lesson_types",
    itemView: List.LessonType,
    itemViewContainer: "tbody"
  });
```

In my controller I have:

```
lessonTypes: function( lessonTypes ) {
  var lessonTypesView;
  lessonTypesView = this.getLessonTypesView( lessonTypes );

  lessonTypesView.on( "childview:edit:lesson:type:clicked", function( child, args ) {
    // a whole bunch of jquery
  });

  App.lessonRegion.show( lessonTypesView );
},

getLessonTypesView: function( lessonTypes ) {
  return new List.LessonTypes({
    collection: lessonTypes
  });
}
```

All of that JQuery basically makes the childview's el (which is a table row) editable by adding `contenteditable="true"` to the `td`'s.

When a row is clicked I want any other table row which happens to be in an editable state to return to it's original, un-editable state. Can I somehow make the sibling views re-render or else have the whole collection re-render before the JQuery does it's thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out not to be too hard. I added this in my controller:

```
lessonTypes: function( lessonTypes ) {
  var lessonTypesView;
  lessonTypesView = this.getLessonTypesView( lessonTypes );

  lessonTypesView.on( "childview:edit:lesson:type:clicked", function( child, args ) {
    var model, collection;
    model = args.model;
    collection = lessonTypesView.collection;

    collection.each( function( mod ) {
      if( mod.id !== model.id ) {
        mod.trigger( "refresh" );
      }
    }, this );
    // a whole bunch of jquery
  });

  App.lessonRegion.show( lessonTypesView );
},
```

The custom event forces the view to re-render. In the view:

```
  List.LessonType = App.Views.ItemView.extend({
    template: "lesson_types/list/lesson_type",
    tagName: "tr",

    triggers: {
      "click #edit-lesson-type" : "edit:lesson:type:clicked"
    },

    modelEvents: {
      "refresh" : "render"  // listening to custom event set in the controller
    }
  });
```

If there's a better way to do this, I'd love to hear it!